# Weird Event Listening in ActionScript3

Tags: javascript, actionscript-3, events

I have a weird quirk in ActionScript. I need to pass the index to a callback function.

Here is my code

```
for (var i:Number = 0; ((i < arrayQueue.length) && uploading); i++)
{
    var lid:ListItemData=ListItemData(arrayQueue[i]);
    var localI:Number= new Number(i); // to copy?
    var errorCallback:Function = function():void { OnUploadError(localI); };
    var progressCallback:Function = function(e:ProgressEvent):void { lid.progress = e; OnUploadProgress(localI); };
    var completeCallback:Function = function():void { Alert.show('callback'+localI.toString()); OnUploadComplete(localI); }; // localI == arrayQueue.length - 1 (when called)
    Alert.show(localI.toString());  // shows current i as expected
    lid.fileRef.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, completeCallback);
    lid.fileRef.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS, progressCallback);
    lid.fileRef.addEventListener(HTTPStatusEvent.HTTP_STATUS, errorCallback);
    lid.fileRef.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, errorCallback);
    lid.fileRef.addEventListener(SecurityErrorEvent.SECURITY_ERROR, errorCallback);

    lid.fileRef.upload(url, 'File');
}
```

Any idea on how to pass in the index to my callbacks? `.upload` does not block.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Passing additional parameters for your callbacks is possible via some kind of delegate function or closure. However it is often considered a bad practice. You may use event `target` property instead to determine your index based on `FileReference`.

**Edit:** here is a sample of using closures:

```
function getTimerClosure(ind : int) : Function {
    return function(event : TimerEvent) {
        trace(ind);
    };
}

for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    var tm : Timer = new Timer(100*i+1, 1);
    tm.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, getTimerClosure(i));
    tm.start();
}
```

This will continuously trace numbers from 0 to 9.

**Edit2:** here is a sample of creating a delegate based on a function closure:

```
function timerHandler(event : Event, ...rest) : void {
    trace(event, rest);
}

function Delegate(scope : Object, func : Function, ...rest) : Function {
    return function(...args) : void {
        func.apply(scope, args.concat(rest));
    }
}

var tm : Timer = new Timer(1000, 1);
tm.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, Delegate(this, this.timerHandler, 1, 2, 3));
tm.start();
```

However this is a bad approach since unsubscribing for such a listener is a hell pain. This in turn will probably cause some memory leakages, which will decrease overall performance of your application. *So, use with caution!*

---

**Bottom line:** if you know how to work with closures, use them - it is a wonderful thing! If you don't care about your application performance in a long perspective, use closures - it's simple!

But if you are unsure about closures, use a more conventional approach. E.g. in your case you could create a `Dictionary` that matches your `FileReference` objects to appropriate indices. Something like that:

```
var frToInd : Dictionary = new Dictionary(false);
// false here wouldn't prevent garbage collection of FileReference objects

for (var i : int = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    // blah-blah stuff with `lib` objects
    frToInd[lib.fileRef] = i;
    // another weird stuff and subscription 
}

function eventListener(event : Event) : void {
    // in the event listener just look up target in the dictionary
    if (frToInd[event.target]) {
        var ind : int = frToInd[event.target];
    } else {
        // Shouldn't happen since all FileReferences should be in 
        // the Dictionary. But if this happens - it's an error.
    }
}
```

*-- Happy coding!*

Comment: The `target` won't work for me because `target` will only get me the `FileReference`, which is not what I need.

Comment: But the `FileReference`s for different `lid`s are also different. At least you could store them in an Array and find necessary one in the callback.

Comment: Also I can bring up the delegate or closure sample. But it's a bad idea to use one.

Comment: Why is it a bad idea to use the closures here? I find your example perfectly fine.

Comment: @Daniel, @Chetan: I added some explanation, delegate creation sample and proper solution to the question.

Answer (score 0):

> I have a weird quirk in ActionScript

It's not a quirk, it's variable scope. You should read this article: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7f9d.html#WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7f8c

And you really shouldn't use anonymous, it just makes everything more confusing. You're actually making multiple copies of the same object.

If the **arrayQueue** is in scope, you can use this code to get the index:

```
GetArrayIndex(e.currentTarget);

function GetArrayIndex(object:Object):Number
{
    for(var i:Number = 0; 0 < arrayQueue.length; i++)
    {
        if(object === arrayQueue[i])
            return i;
    }
}
```

You should consider using an uint for the index.